# Bound an integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, continuity

Let us define, for $x_0 > 0$ and $x_0 \ll 1$,
$$K(x) = \int_{-x_0}^{x - g(x)^2} \frac{f(y)}{x - y}dy, \quad \text{for } x \in [-x_0/4, x_0],$$
and
$$g(x) = \frac{(x_0 - x)|\log(x_0)|}{|\log(x_0 - x)|^2} \quad \text{and} \quad f(y) = \frac{|\log(x_0)|}{|\log(x_0 - y)|^2}.$$
We may show that
$$|K(x) - K(x_0)| \le C\frac{|\log(x_0)| \log|\log(x_0 - x)|}{|\log(x_0 - x)|^2|}, \quad \text{for } x \in [-x_0/4, x_0].$$
Now for $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\varepsilon < x_0$, we define
$$K^\varepsilon(x) = \int_{-x_0}^{x - g(x)^2- \varepsilon^2} \frac{f(y)}{x - y}dy.$$
I would like to know if we have the same kind of inequality
$$|K^\varepsilon(x) - K^\varepsilon(x_0)| \le C\frac{|\log(x_0)| \log|\log(x_0 - x)|}{|\log(x_0 - x)|^2} + h(x_0, x, \varepsilon), \quad \text{for } x \in [-x_0/4, x_0],$$
for $ h(x_0, x, \varepsilon)$ a continuous function going to zero for $x_0 \vee \varepsilon \to 0$ and $x \to x_0$. Just by a continuity argument I reckon we can already conclude. Indeed, we have
$$|K^\varepsilon(x) - K^\varepsilon(x_0)| \le |K(x) - K(x_0)| + |(K(x) - K^\varepsilon(x)) - (K(x_0) - K^\varepsilon(x_0))|$$
and as $K$ is a continuous function we conclude. However, I would like to find an explicit bound for this integral, something similar to the bound we have for $K(x) - K(x_0)$. Is there something obvious I didn't see ? As $\varepsilon$ is chosen smaller than $T$, I would actually like my bound $h$ to be intependent of $\varepsilon$, so that $h(x, x_0)$ and $h \to 0$ for $x_0 \to 0$.